# I added bad js to my website. Now it won't load completely and I can't get to the admin to remove it

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

is there a firefox plugin that will let me ignore a certain snippet of code?

If I turn off js, the page loads but I can't get to the admin because that requires js.

I would like to leave js on, but have my browser simply ignore a couple lines of code.

Possible?

Thanks!

Comment: obviously i can't get to the backend and the moment.

Comment: Hardly possible. What errors do you get?

Comment: What javascript did you add that is breaking the page?

Comment: Always ensure you have FTP access... that way you can just upload the last version from your source control.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try using Firebug.  Add a breakpoint right before the error, then modify the JS before you continue.  Good luck!

Comment: Clever, didn't think of that!

Answer (score 3):

You may be able to whip up a script in [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/748) that can skip the lines, though this will only be when you run it, not when other run it.

The correct answer is to ftp the correct Javascript files to the server or course.

Answer (score 0):

Hy

Try https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/521